# KMBOX for Kernel Canonical Correlation Analysis

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math, machine-learning, correlation

I am currently using [KMBOX toolbox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kmbox/) for kernel [canonical correlation analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation) in MATLAB.

The code here is part of [`km_kcca.m`](https://github.com/steven2358/kmbox/blob/master/lib/km_kcca.m#L76)

```
I = eye(N); Z = zeros(N);
N0 = eye(N)-1/N*ones(N);

% get kernel matrices
K1 = N0*km_kernel(X1,X1,kernel,kernelpar)*N0;
K2 = N0*km_kernel(X2,X2,kernel,kernelpar)*N0;
```

Obviously, [`km_kernel`](https://github.com/steven2358/kmbox/blob/master/lib/km_kernel.m) generate kernel matrices. but what is the meaning of `N0`. Why times `N0`?

Comment: I don't have an explanation for you, but have you checked out the referenced paper for the KCCA algorithm: `Kernel Canonical Correlation Analysis (KCCA), as proposed in D. R. Hardoon, S. Szedmak and J. Shawe-Taylor, "Canonical Correlation Analysis: An Overview with Application to Learning Methods", Neural Computation, Volume 16 (12), Pages 2639--2664, 2004`?

Comment: yep, I have already read that paper, but the code here is not similar as what the paper described.(I.E. the code above , "times N0")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a look at the implementation, and I think the purpose of multiplying by matrix `N0` is to remove the mean vector from the kernel matrix, that way it is zero-centered (which might make sense for simplifying later computations).

Once we have that, we solve the [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem) `Rv = λDv` as `[a,b]=eig(R,D)`, where:

- `R` is a block-diagonal matrix with `K1*K2` on the upper-right corner, `K2*K1` on the lower-left corner, and zero matrices on the diagonal blocks.
- `D` is block-diagonal matrix with `(K1^2+reg*I)` and `(K2^2+reg*I)` as blocks on the diagonals and zero blocks off the diagonal (`reg` is a regularization term to make it more numerically stable)

(actually [the code](https://github.com/steven2358/kmbox/blob/master/lib/km_kcca.m#L85) does this in a slightly different way to avoid numerical problems, and lists three options (commented) to solve it).

PS: I found [these notes](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/classnotes/papers_class/kCCA.pdf) to be helpful.

---

### Example:

I'll use the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/) to help me illustrate the computation symbolically:

```
%% say we built the kernel matrix from data, this is a n-by-n symmetric matrix
n = 3;
K = sym('K',[n n]);
K =  triu(K) + triu(K,1).';
```

This is a symmetric matrix:

```
>> K
K =
[ K1_1, K1_2, K1_3]
[ K1_2, K2_2, K2_3]
[ K1_3, K2_3, K3_3]
```

Now lets remove the mean vector from the matrix (simply compute the mean and subtract it). As expected, the new matrix should have zero mean along the rows/columns:

```
% remove mean-row from the kernel, so that mean(KK,1) == zeros(1,n)
>> KK = K - repmat(mean(K,1),n,1);
>> mean(KK,1)
ans =
[ 0, 0, 0]

% or remove mean-column from the kernel, so that mean(KK,2) == zeros(n,2)
>> KK = K - repmat(mean(K,2),1,n);
>> mean(KK,2)
ans =
 0
 0
 0
```

Interestingly, this could also be done with matrix multiplication (which is used in that code):

```
% first we build the coefficients matrix for n=3
>> N0 = eye(n) - 1/n*ones(n);
>> N0 = sym(N0)
N0 =
[  2/3, -1/3, -1/3]
[ -1/3,  2/3, -1/3]
[ -1/3, -1/3,  2/3]

% pre-multiply to remove average row
>> KK = N0*K;
>> mean(KK,1)
ans =
[ 0, 0, 0]

% post-multiply to remove average column
>> KK = K*N0;
>> mean(KK,2)
ans =
 0
 0
 0
```

Now the code in `km_kcca.m` is doing the multiplication on both sides, this has the effect of removing the average from both rows and columns, and the mean of the matrix will be zero in both directions:

```
>> KK = N0*K*N0;

>> mean(KK,1)
ans =
[ 0, 0, 0]

>> mean(KK,2)
ans =
 0
 0
 0
```

This is the same as doing:

```
>> KK = K - repmat(mean(K,1),n,1);
>> KK = KK - repmat(mean(KK,2),1,n);

>> mean(KK,1)
ans =
[ 0, 0, 0]

>> mean(KK,2)
ans =
 0
 0
 0
```

For what it's worth the zero-centered matrix comes out as follows (for `n=3` case):

[image: N0*K*N0]

```
>> pretty(N0*K*N0)
/ 4 K1_1   4 K1_2   4 K1_3   K2_2   2 K2_3   K3_3                                                                                                   \
| ------ - ------ - ------ + ---- + ------ + ----,                        #1,                                              #3                       |
|    9        9        9       9       9       9                                                                                                    |
|                                                                                                                                                   |
|                                                  K1_1   4 K1_2   2 K1_3   4 K2_2   4 K2_3   K3_3                                                  |
|                        #1,                       ---- - ------ + ------ + ------ - ------ + ----,                        #2                       |
|                                                    9       9        9        9        9       9                                                   |
|                                                                                                                                                   |
|                                                                                                   K1_1   2 K1_2   4 K1_3   K2_2   4 K2_3   4 K3_3 |
|                        #3,                                              #2,                       ---- + ------ - ------ + ---- - ------ + ------ |
\                                                                                                     9       9        9       9       9        9   /

where

         5 K1_2   2 K1_1   K1_3   2 K2_2   K2_3   K3_3
   #1 == ------ - ------ - ---- - ------ - ---- + ----
            9        9       9       9       9      9

         K1_1   K1_2   K1_3   2 K2_2   5 K2_3   2 K3_3
   #2 == ---- - ---- - ---- - ------ + ------ - ------
           9      9      9       9        9        9

         5 K1_3   K1_2   2 K1_1   K2_2   K2_3   2 K3_3
   #3 == ------ - ---- - ------ + ---- - ---- - ------
            9       9       9       9      9       9
```

Comment: An extra question, what's the reason of making a matrix to be the so-called zero-centered?

Comment: I think it improves numerical properties of the kernel matrix and thus avoids an [ill-conditioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) `K`. Here is one paper that discuss this topic: http://www.stat.washington.edu/mmp/Papers/aistats03.pdf

Comment: @user1522378: see Steven's answer (the author of the toolbox).

Answer (score 2):

Amro's answer is correct: the purpose of multiplying by `N0` is to remove the data mean from the kernel matrix. You can find this in the last paragraph of section 3.2.1 of the second referenced paper: F. R. Bach and M. I. Jordan, "Kernel Independent Component Analysis", JMLR, 2002.

The reason is not to avoid numerical problems but because [correlation is typically calculated on zero-mean data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation).

Comment: +1 thanks Steven for chiming in, I somehow missed that [second referenced paper](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/BachJ02.pdf)! Now I understand the reason behind `N0*K*N0`: correlation is computed on centered observation (if we only used a linear kernel, we could have centered the data X1/X2 from the beginning), but because of the "kernel trick" it is no longer trivial to explicitly compute the mean in the implicitly mapped feature space (which can even have infinite number of dimensions as in case of the RBF kernel).

Comment: ... Fortunately we can get the Gram matrix for the centered data in the feature space, and it happens to be the form used above. The article referenced another paper ([Scholkopf et al., 1998](http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/Kernel/kernelPCA_scholkopf.pdf)) for the derivation (see Appendix A)

Comment: In case you're interested, there are some nice papers on the subject of centering data in kernel methods, for instance the recent paper "[An eigenanalysis of data centering in machine learning](http://www.honeine.fr/paul/publi/14.center.pdf)" by P. Honeine.